# Is there a way to override built in property editors on Umbraco 9/10?

Tags: umbraco, umbraco8, umbraco-blog, umbraco9

Hey I'm using umbraco 10 and I'm trying to override the addTag function of the built in "Umbraco.Tags" property editor.. can some body help with that? Can't manage to do it.. the problem with using the built in one is that the tags dosnt have case sensitive.. for example "news" and "News" will be 2 different and I need to change that behavior.. thanks for all helpers.

I have tried to create custom property editor with Angularjs controller and html for view. But cannot find away to connect this to the built in property editor so I can't find away how to override it ..

Comment: Umbraco Tag manager has several limitations, including what you mentioned. I used a document type and a relation type to relate the two document types (Bidirectional). 
It required a few extra steps and restricted users from tagging documents.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is a way. Its open source, so all code is available. :-)

I would probably solve it server-side.  Allow the user to add it in the backoffice. Then subscribe on the ["contentSaving" notification](https://docs.umbraco.com/umbraco-cms/reference/notifications/contentservice-notifications) from the content service and update the property before it is persisted to the database.